# text mining/analyse user commands/questions algorithm or library

Tags: algorithm, libraries, text-mining

I got a financial application and I wish to add to it the ability to get user command or input in textbox and then take the right action. for example, wish the user to write "show the revenue in the last 10 days" and it'll show the revenue to him/her - the point is that I wish it to really understand the meaning of the question, so the previus statement will bring the same results as "do I got any revenue in the last 10 days" or something like that - BI (something like the Wolfram|Alpha engine).

I wonder if there's any opensource library or algorithm books or whatever that I can use to learn the subject. Regards to opensource libraries - I don't mind which language it'll be written in.

I've read about this subject and saw many engines and services (OpenNLP, Apache UIMA, CoreNLP etc.) but did not figure out if they're right for my needs.

Any answer or suggestion is welcome.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field you're talking about is usually called "natural language processing".  It's hard, and an active field of research.  There are various libraries which you could consider based on your preferred programming language and use case:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits

I've used NLTK a little bit.  This field is seriously difficult to get right, so you might want to try to restrict your application to some small set of verbs and nouns such that people are using a controlled vocabulary in the first instance, and then try to extend it beyond that.